# changing the Json output

Tags: php

How can i produce this output from database . I am using php and mysql and want this output by using JSON

but i output in this format

```
{"earthquakes": [
    {
        "eqid": "c0001xgp",
        "magnitude": 8.8,
        "lng": 142.369,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
        "depth": 24.4,
        "lat": 38.322
  },
  {
        "eqid": "2007hear",
        "magnitude": 8.4,
        "lng": 101.3815,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2007-09-12 09:10:26",
        "depth": 30,
        "lat": -4.5172
  }
<--more -->
]}
```

so please guide me how can i update my code ??

i am setting this because i want to fit it for the android app whose code is

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/fetch.php");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
                map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why do you need it formatted?

Comment: I have code for android which process in this format , so i want to fit it for that

Comment: why not use a JSON parser: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html in your android app?

Comment: i have updated the question and now mentioned my android code too . so please if you can suggest me how i can update this code .

Comment: your sample output doesnt match what you expect.

Comment: its working you can check it out over here http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Comment: sure, but your domain example from the php is referring to an `admin` table which has nothing to do with earthquakes.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A proper JSON decoder will be able to read the data, formatted or not.

Comment: i have just taken for example . i have uploaded to a free server where i have already set some of my databases

Comment: But anyways: Pekka said everything. A JSON-Parser doesnt take care of any nice looking formattings. If you have a valid JSON-encoded strinh, a Parser can read it. This doesnt make much sense for me too ^^

Comment: @Pekka6  i have updated my question to make it more easy . I want to produce the output for the android app from my database .The  output is listed above . so please if any suggestions  . i am using this tutorial http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i need was these set of line

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM earthquakes"); 

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
            $arr[] = $obj;
        }

        echo '{"earthquakes":'.json_encode($arr).'}'
```

;

Comment: Even better: `echo json_encode(array('earthquakes' => $arr));`